# How can i bulk ADD URL Rewrite Management

Tags: magento-1.9, url-rewrite, migration, paths, request

How can i add bulk URL Rewrite Management, i need to `migrate new website`, but i have already promoted my old site products, so, after i change new site, old site url return blank page, or empty page. So i have add all my old site url into new site request path, my target path is my new site products url. so i have no problem after change my site.

Answer (score 2):

You can export URL structure and create a .php file in root of magento with below code.

```
<?php
$pageurl['http://oldsiteurl/']='http://newsiteurl/';
$pageurl['http://oldsiteurl/']='http://newsiteurl/';
$pageurl['http://oldsiteurl/']='http://newsiteurl/';
$pageurl['http://oldsiteurl/']='http://newsiteurl/';

$current_url = "http://$_SERVER[HTTP_HOST]$_SERVER[REQUEST_URI]";
if(array_key_exists($current_url, $pageurl))
{    
    $redirect_url = $pageurl[$current_url];
    header("HTTP/1.1 301 Moved Permanently");
    header("Location: $redirect_url"); 
    exit;   
}
```

Include above .php file in index.php to redirect them on new website. .

Comment: make sure above only change in request path not in target path

Comment: This is a core script. You just need to prepare your array according to your changes in URLs.

Comment: bro, i need just bulk add url rewrite management. so how can i add bulk url rewrite